# replace NA in 2nd column of data frame with non-na values in 2nd columns of same data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

The sample/value `s_C_VWPHV0_P002_d` under `Tumor_Sample_Barcode_post` column appears twice. So `s_C_VWPHV0_P002_d` should have 2 `s_C_3438KR_P001_d` label under `Tumor_Sample_Barcode_pre` column. However, there's only 1 `s_C_3438KR_P001_d` and `NA` under `Tumor_Sample_Barcode_pre`. could you please help me duplicate `s_C_3438KR_P001_d` under the `Tumor_Sample_Barcode_pre`? I tried using the following code but it didn't work.

```
df_NA %>% group_by(Tumor_Sample_Barcode_post) %>% dplyr::mutate(Tumor_Sample_Barcode_pre = replace_na(Tumor_Sample_Barcode_pre, !is.na(Tumor_Sample_Barcode_pre)))

df_NA %>% group_by(Tumor_Sample_Barcode_post) %>% mutate(Tumor_Sample_Barcode_pre = case_when(Tumor_Sample_Barcode_pre == NA ~ Tumor_Sample_Barcode_pre))
```

this is how may data looks like

```
df_NA <- structure(list(Tumor_Sample_Barcode_post = c("s_C_VWPHV0_P002_d", 
"s_C_3438KR_P002_d", "s_C_3438KR_P002_d", "s_C_V2MVLR_P002_d", 
"s_C_JXLC4H_P002_d", "s_C_UXUR8D_P002_d", "s_C_XUCF8U_P002_d", 
"s_C_JXLC4H_P002_d", "s_C_XUCF8U_P002_d", "s_C_V2MVLR_P002_d", 
"s_C_VWPHV0_P002_d", "s_C_UXUR8D_P002_d"), Tumor_Sample_Barcode_pre = c(NA, 
NA, "s_C_3438KR_P001_d", NA, "s_C_JXLC4H_P001_d", NA, NA, NA, 
"s_C_XUCF8U_P001_d", "s_C_V2MVLR_P001_d", "s_C_VWPHV0_P001_d", 
"s_C_UXUR8D_P001_d")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), groups = structure(list(
    Tumor_Sample_Barcode_post = c("s_C_3438KR_P002_d", "s_C_JXLC4H_P002_d", 
    "s_C_UXUR8D_P002_d", "s_C_V2MVLR_P002_d", "s_C_VWPHV0_P002_d", 
    "s_C_XUCF8U_P002_d"), .rows = structure(list(2:3, c(5L, 8L
    ), c(6L, 12L), c(4L, 10L), c(1L, 11L), c(7L, 9L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What do yo mean by "corresponding non-NA values"? Your approach actually only says: If the column is `NA`, then take the value of the column (which is `NA`). From where should the "corresponding" values come from?

Comment: non-na value is in the 2nd column. so in the full data there's only 1 non-value value in the 2nd column the rest are NA.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion! ideally your answer should work but not all values in `*_pre` follow the naming convention `P001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get the question right, you have to arrange your dataset and mutate the second column such that the first value of each group gets dragged to the other rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df_NA |> # df is already grouped
    arrange(Tumor_Sample_Barcode_post, Tumor_Sample_Barcode_pre) |> 
    mutate(Tumor_Sample_Barcode_pre = first(Tumor_Sample_Barcode_pre)) |> 
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 12 × 2
   Tumor_Sample_Barcode_post Tumor_Sample_Barcode_pre
   <chr>                     <chr>                   
 1 s_C_3438KR_P002_d         s_C_3438KR_P001_d       
 2 s_C_3438KR_P002_d         s_C_3438KR_P001_d       
 3 s_C_JXLC4H_P002_d         s_C_JXLC4H_P001_d       
 4 s_C_JXLC4H_P002_d         s_C_JXLC4H_P001_d       
 5 s_C_UXUR8D_P002_d         s_C_UXUR8D_P001_d       
 6 s_C_UXUR8D_P002_d         s_C_UXUR8D_P001_d       
 7 s_C_V2MVLR_P002_d         s_C_V2MVLR_P001_d       
 8 s_C_V2MVLR_P002_d         s_C_V2MVLR_P001_d       
 9 s_C_VWPHV0_P002_d         s_C_VWPHV0_P001_d       
10 s_C_VWPHV0_P002_d         s_C_VWPHV0_P001_d       
11 s_C_XUCF8U_P002_d         s_C_XUCF8U_P001_d       
12 s_C_XUCF8U_P002_d         s_C_XUCF8U_P001_d
```